# How to download a file in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

How to download a file in laravel 5.4

I have to download a file in laravel app and extract some values from it and use it in my view. What approach would you recommend for this case?

course.blade.php

```
<tbody>
@foreach($course->episodes()->latest()->get() as $episode)
    <tr>
        <th>{{ $episode->number }}</th>
        <td>{{ $episode->title }}</td>
        <td>{{ $episode->time }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ $episode->download() }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

CourseController

```
public function download(Episode $episode)
{
    return $episode;
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/download/{episode}', 'CourseController@download');
```

Model

```
public function download()
    {
        if(! auth()->check()) return '#';

        $status = false;
        switch ($this->type) {
            case 'free' :
                $status = true;
                break;
            case 'vip' :
                if(user()->isActive()) $status = true;
                break;
            case 'cash' :
                if(user()->checkLearning($this->course)) $status = true;
                break;
        }
        $timestamp = Carbon::now()->addHours(5)->timestamp;
        $hash = Hash::make('fds@#T@#56@sdgs131fasfq'.$this->id.request()->ip().$timestamp);

        return $status ? "/download/$this->id?mac=$hash&t=$timestamp" : "#";
    }
```

I tried but failed.

[Error sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBaK6.png)

Comment: where are you making a request to an external source to get file contents?

Comment: in public/2017  folder

Comment: where are you making a request in the code

Comment: course.blade.php

Comment: alright ... good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out [Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-parameters).

You should modify the CourseController.php

```
public function download($episode)
{
    ...
    $episode = Episode::find($episode);
    if ($episode) {
    }
    else {
    }
    ....
}
```